# Nginx reverse proxy to .Net Core API in docker

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm having trouble trying to get the following to work in Docker

What I want is that when the user requests `http://localhost/api` then NGINX reverse proxies to my .Net Core API running in another container.

Container Host: Windows

Container 1: NGINX

**dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    server {
        location /api1 {
            proxy_pass http://api;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Container 2: .Net Core API

Dead simple - API exposed on port 80 in the container

Then there is the docker-compose.yml

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  api1:
    image: api1
    build:
      context: ./Api1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5010:80"

  nginx:
    image: vc-nginx
    build:
      context: ./infra/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
```

Reading the Docker documentation it states:

> Links allow you to define extra aliases by which a service is
>   reachable from another service. They are not required to enable
>   services to communicate - by default, any service can reach any other
>   service at that service’s name.

So as my API service is called `api1`, I've simply referenced this in the `nginx.conf` file as part of the reverse proxy configuration:

`proxy_pass http://api1;`

Something is wrong as when I enter `http:\\localhost\api` I get a 404 error.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the [nginx location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) configuration.

The 404 error is right, because your configuration is proxying request from `http://localhost/api/some-resource` to a missing resource, because your mapping is for `/api1` path and you're asking for `/api`.

So you should only change the location to `/api` and it will work.

Keep in mind that requests to `http://localhost/api` will be proxied to `http://api1/api` (the path is kept). If your backend is configured to expose api with a prefixing path this is ok, otherwise you will receive another 404 (this time from your service).
To avoid this you should rewrite the path before proxying the request with a rule like this:

```
# transform /api/some-resource/1 to /some-resource/1
rewrite    /api/(.*) /$1 break;
```